# Read data from xlsx file in php and print as php array

Tags: php, file, xlsx

I need a php script which can read the data from an uploaded xlsx file. Also I need to print those data in an array format. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Save as CSV first and after that - parse it with http://gist.github.com/385876